# Populate select fields on change with jquery and json depending on threshold values

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, threshold

I'm trying to use jQuery to populate four select fields dinamically parsing a fourlevel json array for a webshop depending on threshold values.

I hope someone could help how to dinamically change the selects only if the given value is bigger than (or equal to) the minimum value of an interval.

There is a simplified verson of the code on fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/tamben01/844tp5gt/16/

The json array name is prodOpts_0 each of the selects depend on a quantity threshold. (The more the quantity the less the price)

There are four intervals

1 to 19

20 to 49

50 to 99

100 to 999

I'm trying to use the minimum (from) and maximum (to) values from the json array as triggers, but it behaves unexpectedly, I'm not sure how to define if the quantity value is between the proper interval.

The json looks like this

```
    var prodOpts_0 = {
                "qty": [
                     {
                          "option_name": "1",
                          "from": "1",
                          "to": "19",
                          "size": [
                                {
                                     "name": "18x24",
                                     "id": "18x24_1",
                                     "value": "18x24_1",
                                     "label": "18h x 24w",
                                     "selected": "",
                                     "price": "",
                                     "shipping": [
                                          {
                                                "name": "Ground Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_1_ground",
                                                "label": "Ground Shipping",
                                                "price": "3",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          },
                                          {
                                                "name": "2nd Day Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_1_2nd",
                                                "label": "2nd Day Shipping",
                                                "price": "5",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          },
                                          {
                                                "name": "Next Day Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_1_next",
                                                "label": "Next Day Shipping",
                                                "price": "7",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          },
                                     ],
                                     "media": [


                                          {
                                                "name": "3mm Coroplast",
                                                "id": "18x24_1_coroplast",
                                                "value": "18x24_1_coroplast",
                                                "label": "3mm Coroplast",
                                                "price": "0",
                                                "selected": "",
                                                "extras": [
                                                     {
                                                          "name": "None (No Stakes)",
                                                          "id": "none_18x24_1_coroplast",
                                                          "value": "none_18x24_1_coroplast",
                                                          "label": "None (No Stakes)",
                                                          "price": "0",
                                                          "selected": ""


                                                     },

                                                     {
                                                          "name": "With Stakes",
                                                          "id": "stakes_18x24_1_coroplast",
                                                          "value": "stakes_18x24_1_coroplast",
                                                          "label": "With Stakes",
                                                          "price": "2",
                                                          "selected": ""
                                                     }
                                                ]
                                          }
                                     ]
                                }
                          ]
                     },
                     {
                          "option_name": "20",
                          "from": "20",
                          "to": "49",
                          "size": [
                                {
                                     "name": "18x24",
                                     "id": "18x24_20",
                                     "value": "18x24_20",
                                     "label": "18h x 24w",
                                     "selected": "",
                                     "price": "0",
                                     "shipping": [
                                          {
                                                "name": "Ground Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_20_ground",
                                                "label": "Ground Shipping",
                                                "price": "3",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          },

                                          {
                                                "name": "2nd Day Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_20_2nd",
                                                "label": "2nd Day Shipping",
                                                "price": "4",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          },

                                          {
                                                "name": "Next Day Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_20_next",
                                                "label": "Next Day Shipping",
                                                "price": "7",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          },
                                     ],
                                     "media": [
                                          {
                                                "name": "3mm Coroplast",
                                                "id": "18x24_20_coroplast",
                                                "value": "18x24_20_coroplast",
                                                "label": "3mm Coroplast",
                                                "price": "0",
                                                "selected": "",
                                                "extras": [
                                                     {
                                                          "name": "None (No Stakes)",
                                                          "id": "none_18x24_20_coroplast",
                                                          "value": "none_18x24_20_coroplast",
                                                          "label": "None (No Stakes)",
                                                          "price": "0",
                                                          "selected": ""


                                                     },

                                                     {
                                                          "name": "With Stakes",
                                                          "id": "stakes_18x24_20_coroplast",
                                                          "value": "stakes_18x24_20_coroplast",
                                                          "label": "With Stakes",
                                                          "price": "2",
                                                          "selected": ""
                                                     },
                                                ]
                                          }
                                     ]
                                }
                          ]
                     },
                     {
                          "option_name": "50",
                          "from": "50",
                          "to": "99",
                          "size": [
                                {
                                     "name": "18x24",
                                     "id": "18x24_50",
                                     "value": "18x24_50",
                                     "label": "18h x 24w",
                                     "selected": "",
                                     "price": "0",
                                     "shipping": [
                                          {
                                                "name": "Ground Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_50_ground",
                                                "label": "Ground Shipping",
                                                "price": "2",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          },

                                          {
                                                "name": "2nd Day Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_50_2nd",
                                                "label": "2nd Day Shipping",
                                                "price": "4",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          },

                                          {
                                                "name": "Next Day Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_50_next",
                                                "label": "Next Day Shipping",
                                                "price": "6",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          }
                                     ],
                                     "media": [

                                          {
                                                "name": "3mm Coroplast",
                                                "id": "18x24_50_coroplast",
                                                "value": "18x24_50_coroplast",
                                                "label": "3mm Coroplast",
                                                "price": "0",
                                                "selected": "",

                                                "extras": [


                                                     {
                                                          "name": "None (No Stakes)",
                                                          "id": "none_18x24_50_coroplast",
                                                          "value": "none_18x24_50_coroplast",
                                                          "label": "None (No Stakes)",
                                                          "price": "0",
                                                          "selected": ""


                                                     },

                                                     {
                                                          "name": "With Stakes",
                                                          "id": "stakes_18x24_50_coroplast",
                                                          "value": "stakes_18x24_50_coroplast",
                                                          "label": "With Stakes",
                                                          "price": "2",
                                                          "selected": ""

                                                     }

                                                ]
                                          }

                                     ]
                                }

                          ]
                     },

                     {
                          "option_name": "100",
                          "from": "100",
                          "to": "99999",
                          "size": [
                                {
                                     "name": "18x24",
                                     "id": "18x24_100",
                                     "value": "18x24_100",
                                     "label": "18h x 24w",
                                     "selected": "",
                                     "price": "0",
                                     "shipping": [
                                          {
                                                "name": "Ground Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_100_ground",
                                                "label": "Ground Shipping",
                                                "price": "2",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          },

                                          {
                                                "name": "2nd Day Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_100_2nd",
                                                "label": "2nd Day Shipping",
                                                "price": "3",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          },

                                          {
                                                "name": "Next Day Shipping",
                                                "value": "18x24_100_next",
                                                "label": "Next Day Shipping",
                                                "price": "5",
                                                "selected": ""
                                          },

                                     ],
                                     "media": [


                                          {
                                                "name": "3mm Coroplast",
                                                "id": "18x24_100_coroplast",
                                                "value": "18x24_100_coroplast",
                                                "label": "3mm Coroplast",
                                                "price": "0",
                                                "selected": "",

                                                "extras": [


                                                     {
                                                          "name": "None (No Stakes)",
                                                          "id": "none_18x24_100_coroplast",
                                                          "value": "none_18x24_100_coroplast",
                                                          "label": "None (No Stakes)",
                                                          "price": "0",
                                                          "selected": ""

                                                     },

                                                     {
                                                          "name": "With Stakes",
                                                          "id": "stakes_18x24_100_coroplast",
                                                          "value": "stakes_18x24_100_coroplast",
                                                          "label": "With Stakes",
                                                          "price": "2",
                                                          "selected": ""

                                                     }

                                                ]
                                          }

                                     ]
                                }

                          ]
                     }

                ]

          };
```

The jQuery code is this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#qty_0').change(loadSizeShippingOptions_0);
                $.proxy(loadSizeShippingOptions_0, $('#qty_0'))();

                $('#size_options').change(loadShippingOptions_0);
                $.proxy(loadShippingOptions_0, $('#size_options'))();

                $('#media_options').change(loadExtraOptions_0);
                $.proxy(loadExtraOptions_0, $('#media_options'))();


          });

          function loadSizeShippingOptions_0() {
                for (var i = 0; i < prodOpts_0.qty.length; i++) {

                     var minValue = prodOpts_0.qty[i].from,
                         maxValue = prodOpts_0.qty[i].to;

                     if (minValue <= $(this).val() && maxValue >= $(this).val()) {
                          $('#size_options').html('');
                          $.each(prodOpts_0.qty[i].size, function(index, value) {
                                $("#size_options").append('<option ' + value.selected + ' value="' + value.value + '">' + value.label + '</option>');

                                for (var s = 0; s < prodOpts_0.qty[i].size.length; s++) {
                                     if (prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[s].id == $("#size_options").val()) {
                                          $('#shipping_variables').html('');
                                          $.each(prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[s].shipping, function(index, value) {
                                                $("#shipping_variables").append('<option ' + value.selected + ' value="' + value.value + '">' + value.label + ' + $' + value.price + '</option>');
                                          });
                                     }
                                }
                                for (var m = 0; m < prodOpts_0.qty[i].size.length; m++) {
                                     if (prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].id == $("#size_options").val()) {
                                          $('#media_options').html('');
                                          $.each(prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media, function(index, value) {
                                                $("#media_options").append('<option ' + value.selected + ' value="' + value.value + '">' + value.label + '</option>');


                                                for (var x = 0; x < prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media.length; x++) {
                                                     if (prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media[x].id == $("#media_options").val()) {
                                                          $('#extra_variables').html('');

                                                          $.each(prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media[x].extras, function(index, value) { //console.log("prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media[x].extras");
                                                                $("#extra_variables").append('<option ' + value.selected + ' value="' + value.value + '">' + value.label + '</option>');


                                                          });
                                                     }
                                                }
                                          });
                                     }
                                }

                          });

                     }
                }
          };

          function loadShippingOptions_0() {
                for (var i = 0; i < prodOpts_0.qty.length; i++) {
                     /***************/
                     for (var s = 0; s < prodOpts_0.qty[i].size.length; s++) {
                          if (prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[s].id == $("#size_options").val()) {
                                $('#shipping_variables').html('');
                                $.each(prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[s].shipping, function(index, value) {
                                     $("#shipping_variables").append('<option ' + value.selected + ' value="' + value.value + '">' + value.label + ' + $' + value.price + '</option>');
                                });
                          }
                     }
                     /***************/
                     for (var m = 0; m < prodOpts_0.qty[i].size.length; m++) {
                          if (prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].id == $("#size_options").val()) {
                                $('#media_options').html('');
                                $.each(prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media, function(index, value) {
                                     $("#media_options").append('<option ' + value.selected + ' value="' + value.value + '">' + value.label + '</option>');

                                     for (var x = 0; x < prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media.length; x++) {
                                          if (prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media[x].id == $("#media_options").val()) {
                                                $('#extra_variables').html('');

                                                $.each(prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media[x].extras, function(index, value) {
                                                     $("#extra_variables").append('<option ' + value.selected + ' value="' + value.value + '">' + value.label + '</option>');


                                                });
                                          }
                                     }
                                });
                          }
                     }
                }
          };

          function loadExtraOptions_0() {
                for (var i = 0; i < prodOpts_0.qty.length; i++) {
                     for (var m = 0; m < prodOpts_0.qty[i].size.length; m++) {

                          for (var x = 0; x < prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media.length; x++) {
                                if (prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media[x].id == $("#media_options").val()) {
                                     $('#extra_variables').html('');

                                     $.each(prodOpts_0.qty[i].size[m].media[x].extras, function(index, value) {
                                          $("#extra_variables").append('<option ' + value.selected + ' value="' + value.value + '">' + value.label + '</option>');


                                     });
                                }
                          }

                     }
                }
          };
```

The html is this:

```
             <div class="form_line">
          <label>Quantity</label>
          <input type="number" name="quantity[0]" id="qty_0" value="1" min="1" max="999" step="1"/>


     </div>

     <div class="form_line">
          <label>Size</label>
          <select id="size_options" name="size_options">
                <option value=''>Choose size</option>
          </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form_line">
          <label>Media</label>
          <select id="media_options" name="media_options">

                <option value=''>Choose media</option>

          </select>
     </div>
     <div class="form_line">
          <label>Extras</label>
          <select id="extra_variables" name="extra_variables">

                <option value=''>Choose extra</option>

          </select>
     </div>

     <div class="form_line">
          <label>Shipping</label>
          <select id="shipping_variables" name="shipping_variables">

                <option value=''>Select shipping</option>

          </select>
     </div>
```

Basically I use

```
if (minValue <= $(this).val() && maxValue >= $(this).val()) {
```

to check if the quantity value is between the minimum and the maximum, but it doesnt work as I expected. Even if it populates the selects on change, it displays wrong values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have set your values as Strings instead of numbers in your json:

```
                      "from": "1",
                      "to": "19",
```

Therefore in these lines you are setting `minValue` and `maxValue` to String values, which will not give the answers you might expect in the rest of your code.

```
 var minValue = prodOpts_0.qty[i].from,
 maxValue = prodOpts_0.qty[i].to;
```

Comment: Or just write them as numbers without the inverted commas from the very start in the json

Comment: Yep, but that sometimes equals handing the task over to backend developer if you are dealing with frontend only :) Nevertheless you've got the point

Comment: Thanks mwarren, removing inverted commas did the trick, so I use commas only for string values